# ChartJS Issues / Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, charts, chart.js

I've got an issue with ChartJS. I've wanting to add charts to different areas of my site, and I've been able to get it to work with one chart but now I'm trying to add a separate chart (that isn't even on the same page as the first) and it won't load at all.  It's the oddest thing.

Here's my script for the charts:

```
var wins = $("#wins").text();
var losses = $("#losses").text();
var draws = $("#draws").text();
var winsstrike = $("#wins-strike").text();
var winsgrapple = $("#wins-grapple").text();
var winssubmit = $("#wins-submit").text();
var winsother = $("#wins-other").text();

var recorddata = [{
        value: 1*wins,
        color: "#eb3f3d",
        label: "Wins"
    }, {
        value: 1*losses,
        color: "#ec582a",
        label: "Losses"
    }, {
        value: 1*draws,
        color: "#f8a430",
        label: "Draws"
    }

    ]

    var recordoptions = {
        animation: true,
        segmentShowStroke : true,
        segmentStrokeColor : "#191919",
        percentageInnerCutout : 70

    };

var winsdata = [{
        value: 1*winsstrike,
        color: "#eb3f3d",
        label: "Strike"
    }, {
        value: 1*winsgrapple,
        color: "#E82521",
        label: "Grappling"
    }, {
        value: 1*winssubmit,
        color: "#CB1815",
        label: "Submission"
    }, {
        value: 1*winsother,
        color: "#A61411",
        label: "Other"
    }

    ]

    var winsoptions = {
        animation: true,
        segmentShowStroke : true,
        segmentStrokeColor : "#191919",
        percentageInnerCutout : 90
    };

    var c = $('#recordChart');
    var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
    var ctx = document.getElementById("recordChart").getContext("2d");
    myNewChart = new Chart(ct).Doughnut(recorddata, recordoptions);

    var c1 = $('#winsbyChart');
    var ct1 = c1.get(0).getContext('2d');
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById("winsbyChart").getContext("2d");
    myNewChart1 = new Chart(ct1).Doughnut(winsdata, winsoptions);
```

I have no clue why they won't work; the first chart, posting the `#recordChart` works flawlessly, but the second doesn't.  I know the code is fine because I built a fiddle for it. I just can't figure out why the hell it won't work on the second chart (`#winsbyChart`).

Is there a conflict between the charts I'm not seeing?  This is just so frustrating.

UPDATE:
I've deleted the first chart call (not the options or data), and the second appears.  They seem to be conflicting with one another somehow.  I'm also calling an external JS file; the script isn't embedded in my code.  Below is the ENTIRE JS script - which is specifically used for these charts.  Perhaps it's something to do with how I've set up the script file?

```
(function( root, $, undefined ) {
    "use strict";

    $(function () {
        // DOM ready, take it away

var wins = $("#wins").text();
var losses = $("#losses").text();
var draws = $("#draws").text();
var winsstrike = $("#wins-strike").text();
var winsgrapple = $("#wins-grapple").text();
var winssubmit = $("#wins-submit").text();
var winsother = $("#wins-other").text();

var recorddata = [{
        value: 1*wins,
        color: "#eb3f3d",
        label: "Wins"
    }, {
        value: 1*losses,
        color: "#ec582a",
        label: "Losses"
    }, {
        value: 1*draws,
        color: "#f8a430",
        label: "Draws"
    }

    ]

    var recordoptions = {
        animation: true,
        segmentShowStroke : true,
        segmentStrokeColor : "#191919",
        percentageInnerCutout : 80

    };

var winsdata = [{
        value: 1*winsstrike,
        color: "#eb3f3d",
        label: "Strike"
    }, {
        value: 1*winsgrapple,
        color: "#E82521",
        label: "Grappling"
    }, {
        value: 1*winssubmit,
        color: "#CB1815",
        label: "Submission"
    }, {
        value: 1*winsother,
        color: "#A61411",
        label: "Other"
    }

    ]

    var winsoptions = {
        animation: true,
        segmentShowStroke : true,
        segmentStrokeColor : "#191919",
        percentageInnerCutout : 80
    };



    var c = $('#recordChart');
    var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
    var ctx = document.getElementById("recordChart").getContext("2d");
    myNewChart = new Chart(ct).Doughnut(recorddata, recordoptions);

    var c1 = $('#winsbyChart');
    var ct1 = c1.get(0).getContext('2d');
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById("winsbyChart").getContext("2d");
    myNewChart1 = new Chart(ct1).Doughnut(winsdata, winsoptions);


    });

} ( this, jQuery ));
```

Comment: Did you inspect the source that's being served by Wordpress? There may be a cached javascript file being served to you that doesn't have your new code.

Comment: I have.  Everything seems fine.  It's so weird.

Comment: Can you share a public URL for the site?

Comment: I can't, unfortunately.

Comment: I can, however let you know that I just did some other tests and it seems it's because there's a second chart.  I deleted the first chart code (not the data or options) and the second worked.  It seems the charts are conflicting for some reason.  I should also note that I'm calling a JS file, the script isn't embedding in the actual page code itself; it's being called externally and on Dom Ready

Comment: Updated the original post with the FULL JS file I'm calling these from.